# How do I request a response from Firebase Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase Functions and TypeScript.  I am trying to make a request from the client (Unity and C#) to the server (Firebase Functions and TypeScript).

My server logs show a 200 status code with no warning or errors.  However, when I receive the response, it faults.

Client Code:

```
public void CallServer(UnityAction<string> callback)
{
    var function = MyFirebaseFunctions.GetHttpsCallable("myFunction");
    function.CallAsync().ContinueWith((response) =>
    {
        if (response.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Fault!"); //Faults every time
        }
        else
        {
            string answer = response.Result.Data.ToString();
            Debug.Log(answer);
            callback(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

Server Code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>
{
    response.send('{json:here}');
});
```

I do not know why it is faulting, nor do I know how to find more information.  If I try to debug `response`, my IDE just says no.  Can anyone with some more experience explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually mixing up "standard" [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with [HTTP Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Your Cloud Function code ("Server Code") is "standard" HTTP Cloud Functions code, with

```
... functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {...})
```

While your Unity code is calling an HTTP Callable Cloud Function, with

```
var function = MyFirebaseFunctions.GetHttpsCallable("myFunction");
```

---

The best way is to adapt the Cloud Function code as follows:

```
export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {foo: 'bar'};
});
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for more details.